# Splash screen error: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Drawable

Tags: android, kotlin, drawable, splash-screen

I'm trying to implement a splash screen to my android app by following
[this article](https://android.jlelse.eu/right-way-to-create-splash-screen-on-android-e7f1709ba154). I've followed it step by step but whenever i try to run the app, it instantly crashes and i get the following error in my logcat:

```
2019-01-05 10:46:33.682 2265-2265/com.example.khoi.parkingapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.khoi.parkingapp, PID: 2265
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.khoi.parkingapp/com.example.khoi.parkingapp.SplashActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Drawable com.example.khoi.parkingapp:drawable/splash_background with resource ID #0x7f07008d
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2955)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3030)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1696)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6938)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Drawable com.example.khoi.parkingapp:drawable/splash_background with resource ID #0x7f07008d
     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/splash_background.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f07008d
        at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawableForCookie(ResourcesImpl.java:837)
        at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawable(ResourcesImpl.java:659)
        at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawableForDensity(Resources.java:891)
        at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:833)
        at android.content.Context.getDrawable(Context.java:605)
        at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable(ContextCompat.java:463)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:203)
        at android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getDrawableIfKnown(TintTypedArray.java:86)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:260)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:182)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.getDelegate(AppCompatActivity.java:520)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:71)
        at com.example.khoi.parkingapp.SplashActivity.onCreate(SplashActivity.kt:10)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7183)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1220)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2908)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3030)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1696)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6938)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
     Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #8: <bitmap> requires a valid 'src' attribute
        at android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable.updateStateFromTypedArray(BitmapDrawable.java:823)
        at android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable.inflate(BitmapDrawable.java:754)
        at android.graphics.drawable.DrawableInflater.inflateFromXmlForDensity(DrawableInflater.java:146)
        at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInnerForDensity(Drawable.java:1322)
        at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:1311)
        at android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable.inflateLayers(LayerDrawable.java:284)
        at android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable.inflate(LayerDrawable.java:194)
        at android.graphics.drawable.DrawableInflater.inflateFromXmlForDensity(DrawableInflater.java:146)
        at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInnerForDensity(Drawable.java:1322)
2019-01-05 10:46:33.682 2265-2265/com.example.khoi.parkingapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlForDensity(Drawable.java:1281)
        at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawableForCookie(ResourcesImpl.java:824)
            ... 24 more
```

Here is my **splash_background.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
            android:drawable="@color/colorPrimary"/>

    <item>
        <bitmap
                android:gravity="center"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: post your splash_background.xml and layout in which you are using it

Comment: @EndUser i didn't create a layout for my `SplashAcitivity` according to the article

Comment: Any idea how can i use mipmap or animation in Splash screen

Comment: I found that using a [shape](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40845366/1820553) is a faster solution.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Thanks to Alexander for narrowing down the error, I found this [post](https://medium.com/@garmseven/so-i-checked-and-tried-to-build-my-splash-screen-from-zero-following-the-tutorial-of-with-splash-ec292e4787f) that fixes exactly my issue:

I fixed my **splash_background.xml** to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
            android:drawable="@color/colorPrimary"/>

    <item>
        <bitmap
                android:gravity="center"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

Apparently, the `src` you need needs to be in the `drawable` folder and it has be a .png not a .xml

Comment: This error also shows up when the drawable is in a platform version qualified drawable folder like `drawable-v21` and you run the app on a device with a lower android version

Comment: @Barcode Did you have to move the ic_launcher files from the `mipmap` folder to the `drawable` folder too?

Comment: Looks like `mipmap` folder cannot be used for splash screen images.

Comment: is this true today?

Comment: @Gel yes it is, I just confirmed it

Comment: My app have used the drawable, but it's still not working.
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:id="@android:id/background">
        <bitmap
                android:src="@drawable/ic_star_outline_12dp"
                android:tint="@color/star"/>
    </item>

    <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
        <bitmap
                android:src="@drawable/ic_star_filled_12dp"
                android:tint="@color/star"/>
    </item>
</layer-list>`

Answer (score 9):

For my part, this solution did not solve the problem. To fix it I declare the background image of the splash screen like this:

```
<item android:drawable="@color/colorPrimary" />

<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:gravity="center" />
```

Answer (score 3):

If you look this line here:

> Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #8:  requires a valid 'src' attribute

It seems that the issue is an invalid source for an drawable in your layout.

Answer (score 2):

Many people these days are using mipmaps with multiple images - if you want to use vector assets then replace your item tag (the one that has the bitmap in 'background_splash.xml' or whatever named it) with this:

```
<item
    android:height="48dp"
    android:width="48dp"
    android:drawable="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:gravity="center" />
```

Note that the height/width are my own and can be replaced. Also, this only works on API level 23 and above. If using lower, you could do this:

```
<item
    android:top="48dp"
    android:bottom="48dp"
    android:left="48dp"
    android:right="48dp"
    android:drawable="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:gravity="center" />
```