How to apply drawable.xml file in colors in android
<color name="backgroundColor">@drawable/bg_rounded_horizontal_gradient_theme</color> 

When I am trying to apply drawable.xml inside the colors not working.
Can any one help we how to apply the below xml file
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <gradient
        android:angle="0"
        android:endColor="@color/clr_theme_indigo"
        android:startColor="@color/clr_theme_green"
        android:type="linear" />

    <corners android:radius="@dimen/_4sdp" />
</shape>


You cannot use drawable to set value for @color type, follow this answer for create background with drawable - https://stackoverflow.com/a/40845366/5055519

Yuo need a number like following example : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13929877/how-to-make-gradient-background-in-android  Use following to get color from string https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5248583/how-to-get-a-color-from-hexadecimal-color-string

@jdweng actually I have two differt xml files created in drawables.xml.if it in dark mode I want to apply one xml file .and if it is light mode want to apply another drawable.xml file
